# ng-click inside a form modal doesn't fire event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I just wrote that simple button that open a modal. In this modal I put a "Close" button that fires a "closeLogin()" function that works well. The same way I create a beer button inside the login form to launch a "doTestme()" function but it is never launched. Please see below:

**Button that correctly trigger the modal:**

```
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Welcome">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <button type="button" class="button" ng-click="login()">Log-in Test, click on the beer!</button>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

**The "MainCtrl" that handle the $scope for this:**

```
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  $scope.doTestme = function() {
    alert("test ok");
  };
```

**Modal that correctly pop-out:**

```
<script id="templates/login.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeLogin()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form ng-submit="doLogin()">
      <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Username</span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.username">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password" style="-webkit-flex: 1 0 100px;"><button type="button" ng-click="doTestme()" class="button button-icon ion-beer" style="font-size:35px;"></button>
    </label>
    <label class="item">
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

It's as if the ng-click is never watched, I don't have any errors in console, no way to debug this so... Any idea?

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEpNGB

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use buttons inside label.It will not work properly.
Just change the container from `<label>` to `<div>`

```
<div class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password" style="-webkit-flex: 1 0 100px;">
           <button type="button" ng-click="doTestme()" class="button button-icon ion-beer" style="font-size:35px;"></button>
        </div>
```

Check this working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByPKzy)

Comment: It's actually interesting why `ng-click` wouldn't work inside `label` tag?

Comment: Thank you! Indeed your solution solve my problem, searching for an explanation I found that label is linked to form input unlike div that's linked to current controler (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#labeled-control).

Comment: Thank you very much. This saved my day :-)

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe the solution was that simple.

Comment: It's not just buttons. Any `ng-click` inside label may not work properly. I had one `ng-click` inside `button` and another inside `anchor` tag and both were wrapped by a `label`. Once it is changed to `div`, the click event worked.

Answer (score -2):

In first moment i tried two things:

> 1. Change the function to "doAlert()"
> 2. Change the button to a normal link " test"

It's worked! But few minutes after the link not fired anymore the alert box.

I tried just in CodePlen. Please do it outside there and send a feed back.